# Installing a firefox extension via terminal?

Tags: command-line, firefox, firefox-extensions

Is this possible? Ideally, I'm trying to make script which will take files (my extension backup files) and replace or install them into other user's computer, with all settings saved. Is this possible. It's ok even if I have to replace whole Mozilla Firefox directory, but it would be better to install only extension with all settings saved. I cannot use gui, so I'm looking for terminal only. For example a bash script and some files which I can give to customers and they would easy install it. Is this possible? The extensions I'm trying to install this way on people's computer is **user agent overrider**.

Comment: Are we talking extensions or plugins? because they are very different from each other (Addon is an .xpi while plugin is an .so - shared object)

Comment: Extension, not plugin.

Comment: Yeah. Did you know everything is possible to install via terminal? ;)

Comment: Of course, the question is: How? :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

download the extension

```
$ wget http://www.addons...../extension-name
$ firefox extension-name
```

example on Ubuntu-it Menu :

```
$ wget https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/storage/public-staging/4684/ubuntu_it_menu-1.1.0-fx.xpi
$ firefox ubuntu_it_menu-1.1.0-fx.xpi
```

info : 'https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ubuntu-it-menu/?src=search
'

Comment: Thanks! But, is it possible to just copy some files from my firefox directory, and then replace some files on other computer, so that firefox on other computer has the same extenssion with all settings saved? Or even copy he entire firefox directory?

Comment: I tried this with cookies & it works but i don't know if that work well with extensions when i copied it i saw the extension still installed but i haven't tried them

Comment: Ok, tell me what files to copy, and i'll try it. Thanks!

Comment: i copied the main folder /home/username/.mozilla 
& you'll find a dir 'extension' "just for checking"

Comment: My extension folder is empty :(

Comment: that was the mozilla ext
get in the firefox folder then vag5t37f.default you're gonna find an other ext dir

Comment: You do not need sudo to install, in fact you should not use sudo as that would run firefox as root.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen maybe he wanted to install it for all the useres with -install-global-extension

Comment: That would not install an extension for all users.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options 
--register-global Registers XULRunner on the system for all users. Must be run as admin / root. & you need the sudo to be as root am i right Mr. @bodhi.zazen .?

Comment: how can I get the`.xpi` for example for this https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/vimium-ff/

Answer (score 1):

This took me some time but here is a solution for the scripters out there. Essentially you have to place every .xpi as `<addon id>.xpi` into the extensions folder you wish.

```
EXTENSIONS_SYSTEM='/usr/share/mozilla/extensions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}/'
EXTENSIONS_USER=`echo ~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/extensions/`

get_addon_id_from_xpi () { #path to .xpi file
    addon_id_line=`unzip -p $1 install.rdf | egrep '<em:id>' -m 1`
    addon_id=`echo $addon_id_line | sed "s/.*>\(.*\)<.*/\1/"`
    echo "$addon_id"
}

get_addon_name_from_xpi () { #path to .xpi file
    addon_name_line=`unzip -p $1 install.rdf | egrep '<em:name>' -m 1`
    addon_name=`echo $addon_name_line | sed "s/.*>\(.*\)<.*/\1/"`
    echo "$addon_name"
}

# Installs .xpi given by relative path
# to the extensions path given
install_zipped () {
    xpi="${PWD}/${1}"
    extensions_path=$2
    new_filename=`get_addon_id_from_xpi $xpi`.xpi
    new_filepath="${extensions_path}${new_filename}"
    addon_name=`get_addon_name_from_xpi $xpi`
    if [ -f "$new_filepath" ]; then
        echo "File already exists: $new_filepath"
        echo "Skipping installation for addon $addon_name."
    else
        cp "$xpi" "$new_filepath"
    fi
}
```

And now to install Adblock..

```
wget https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/downloads/latest/1865/addon-1865-latest.xpi
install_for_user addon-1865-latest.xpi $EXTENSIONS_USER
```

Now if you start your firefox, you will be greeted with a question to install Adblock.